# Irregular spacing in writing a palindrome pattern

Tags: c++, palindrome

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    int space=n-i;
    for(int j=1;j<=space;j++){
      cout<<" ";
    }
    for(int k=i;k>=1;k--){
      cout<<k<<" ";
    }
    for(int l=2;l<=i;l++){
      cout<<l<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code for printing a palindrome pattern but the output I received has irregular spacing and no matter what I couldn't find the error in the code.

[image]

Comment: I guess the font type tricks you. The characters have different widths... So the space is shorter than a digit

Comment: If you DO use a monospaced font, replace the space with something else, like "x", to check if you have enough of them. You need 2x the number of spaces compared to the line count (minus 1). Ex: on 5 lines, you need (5-1)*2 spaces for first one, (5-2)*2 for next etc.

Comment: But I tried compiling in different compilers including online one's and it still results in similar output @simre

Comment: @ALTHAFABDULSALAM Ohh yes. You have a missing *2. You need: `for(int j=1;j<=2*space;j++){`  https://godbolt.org/z/r38TEvWcz

Comment: Yes Thanks...that did work fine but could you please tell what was the mistake in not multiplying the space by a factor of 2? I haven't really understood the reason for the error that I encountered @simre

Comment: @ALTHAFABDULSALAM Because you need to add spaces for the numbers below, and the spaces below. And you have the same number of numbers up to the "start" as spaces thus you need 2*spaces. Eg.: 3rd line is: `3 2 1 2 3` For the line before you have 1 less character. BUT! you also have a space after 3. So you need 2 spaces. FOr the 1st line you have 2 less characters, but you also have 2 spaces what you have to cover, so for the 1st line you will need 4 spaces. Tell me if it is not clear... Just open a text editor and type it by yourself and I think you will see why do you need 2*.

Comment: Thanks alot..I got it now to keep that constant spacing in each row before the middle element to makeup for the extra digits and spaces in each subsequent rows. But why was the factor of "2" used? Like what was the logic to get that factor "2"..i did understand the idea behind but not the reason why..@simre

Comment: @ALTHAFABDULSALAM Because in the `space` variable you only have the number of digits "missing" from the actual row. But there are the same number of spaces "missing" too. So you simply multiply by 2 to get the correct offset.

Comment: Yea I got it now. Thank you so much :) @simre

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "correct" spacing is ***where all the `1`'s line up***. Here are some steps you could try to solve the problem:

**1. How is the position of `1` determined?**
The position should be determined by the last line, starting with `n` — since we don't require any spaces on the front, according to your program.

**2. At which position will `1` appear on the last line?**
Before the character `1`, there are spaces and other numbers — **n-1** numbers from `n` to `2`, and also the same number of spaces, since 1 space is presented after every character, except the last, which doesn't matter here. In total, **2(n-1)** characters before `1`.

**3. Finally, How many spaces are required before line `k`?**
For line `k`, we can use the above step to know that before the character `1` there are **2(k-1)** characters, but we need **2(n-1)** to fill the length. Thus, we can obtain the required space in front of the line as **2(n-1)-2(k-1) = 2(n-k)**. That's why you need the "times 2" over there on line 7.

---

Try to find *steps* toward problems.